# create cors entry for webapp with azure management fluent library

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk

How to specify CORS settings for an existing Azure web app from Azure Management Fluent. Is there a code example?

The following code does not work.
(siteconfig is null)

```
IWebApp app = AzureCloud.WebApps.List().FirstOrDefault(s = > s.Name == "myapp");
if (!app.Inner.SiteConfig.Cors.AllowedOrigins.Contains(ao)) 
{
    app.Inner.SiteConfig.Cors.AllowedOrigins.Add(ao);
    app.Update().Apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this [article](https://blog.bitscry.com/2019/05/02/getting-azure-web-app-details-from-the-management-api/).

```
 SiteConfigResourceInner siteConfig = new SiteConfigResourceInner();
 siteConfig.Cors.AllowedOrigins.Add(ao);
 azure.WebApps.Inner.CreateOrUpdateConfigurationAsync(resourceGroup, app.Name, siteConfig);
```